# What to do about old SO questions which are a good fit for DSP?

Tags: discussion

Reading [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8267/1273) question which is relatively new (also migrated from SO), I found a link contained in the question to a very related, old and answered [question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248670/lane-detection-in-an-artificial-environment).

The question is, in my opinion, a beautiful fit for DSP. But, it is old, with an accepted answer, and 2 years inactive.

I am not saying that I will go hunting for questions like this, but sometimes, looking and browsing around, I will find them. I flag new questions regularly (especially when I just discovered DSP) when I run across them, but flagging something so old, which seems comfortable on SO makes me a little... uncomfortable. So, I'd like some advice on how to proceed :)

Comment: @PeterK. I didn't know about no migration for old questions. But still, is there anything to be done / should anything be done about those (probably very few) excellent questions that simply did not have a better site before than SO and were on-topic at a time, but would be a good fit here and interesting to the community?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/q/124/29

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing you can do, if the question is older than 60 days. [SO disables migration for posts older than 60 days.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)

However, I think there are a couple of things that can possibly be done:

1. Post an answer to a related DSP.SE question, with a link to relevant SO questions. Perhaps mark the answer Community Wiki so we can go back and update it.
2. Edit some of our Tags, and put links to relevant SO questions in the long-form version of the tag description.